# No Sound for Dell Optiplex GX520

Tags: 10.10, sound

I have fresh installed ubuntu 10.10 (maverick) for my desktop pc. The audio is on board and have small speaker inside the CPU. The problem is there has no audio. Anyone could help me or any method that could i fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Type `alsamixer` in terminal and then look for "MONO" (keep pressing left until you find it)

Press M to unmute it and Up or Down keys to change the volume.

(I have an Optiplex as well)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if the drivers are working?
To test this click:
*System->Preferences->Sound*
look under the hardware section there. See if there is anything on the list and if you can choose one and click test.
If you don't see anything there then try:
System->Administration->Additional Drivers
run that and it may detect other drivers it needs for audio, you will have to be connected to the net to download the driver.